# how do I write a python one-liner to create a list of all words in a file?

Tags: python, list, file, cpu-word

Given an ascii file I'd like a python one-liner to create a list of words in the file.

Let tfile contain the following 2 lines

```
abc xyz abc mno
tuv xyz qrs abc
```

There are 8 words in the file and 5 unique words.

If I assign

```
file='tfile'
```

the following one-liner will create a set with the 5 unique words in tfile

```
s=set(open(file).read().split())
```

where the output is {'abc', 'mno', 'qrs', 'tuv', 'xyz'}

However if I try something similar to get a list of all words in the file, namely

```
l=list(open(file).read().split(" "))
```

I get the following

['abc', 'xyz', 'abc', 'mno\ntuv', 'xyz', 'qrs', 'abc\n']

which doesn't quite work because the last word of each line has a newline appended to it.

If I add strip() to the statement as in

```
l=list(open(file).read().strip().split(" "))
```

I get the following, which is better, but still contains a newline which is appended to the first word of the next line in the file.

['abc', 'xyz', 'abc', 'mno', '\ntuv', 'xyz', 'qrs', 'abc']

So 2 questions:
(1) is there a one-liner which does what I want? and
(2) why does the set of unique words work so nicely, without getting any newline characters?

Comment: before `split(' ')` do `.replace('\n', ' ' )` to replace linebreaks with an space

Comment: Did you add an argument to `split` and not even notice, or is this someone else's code that you're trying to understand and modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a `" "` as a argument to the split in the second example. At first, you have

```
s=set(open(file).read().split())
```

But then, you do

```
l=list(open(file).read().split(" "))
```

The key is the `split(" ")`. Without it Python will just split on anything considered whitespace, but with it it is restricted to spaces.

So all you need is

```
l=list(open(file).read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of unique words, you can first create a set and then convert to a list.

```
l=list(set(open(file).read().split()))
```